# Sharing scope between controller & directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've created a directive to wrap a jQuery plugin, and I pass a config object for the plugin from the controller to the directive. (works)

In the config object is a callback that I want to call on an event. (works)

In the callback, I want to modify a property on the controller's $scope, which *does not work*. Angular does not recognize that the property has changed for some reason, which leads me to believe that the $scope in the callback is different than the controller's $scope. My problem is I just don't why.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

---

[**Click here for Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/simshaun/qxjck/)

---

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
    .directive('datepicker', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                // Uncommenting the line below causes
                // the "date changed!" text to appear,
                // as I expect it would.
                // scope.dateChanged = true;

                var dateInput = angular.element('.datepicker')

                dateInput.datepicker(scope.datepickerOpts);

                // The datepicker fires a changeDate event
                // when a date is chosen. I want to execute the
                // callback defined in a controller.
                // ---
                // PROBLEM: 
                // Angular does not recognize that $scope.dateChanged
                // is changed in the callback. The view does not update.
                dateInput.bind('changeDate', scope.onDateChange);
            }
        };
    });

var myModule = angular.module('myModule', ['app'])
    .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.dateChanged = false;

        $scope.datepickerOpts = {
            autoclose: true,
            format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
        };

        $scope.onDateChange = function () {
            alert('onDateChange called!');

            // ------------------
            // PROBLEM AREA:
            // This doesnt cause the "date changed!" text to show.
            // ------------------
            $scope.dateChanged = true;

            setTimeout(function () {
                $scope.dateChanged = false;
            }, 5000);
        };
    }]);
```

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <p ng-show="dateChanged">date changed!</p>
    <input type="text" value="02-16-2012" class="datepicker" datepicker="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a number of scope issues at work in your demo. First , within the `dateChange` callback, even though the function itself is declared inside the controller, the context of `this` within the callback is the bootstrap element since it is within a bootstrap handler.

Whenever you change angular scope values from within third party code , angular needs to know about it by  using `$apply`. Generally best to keep all third party scopes inside the directive.

A more angular apprroach is to use `ng-model` on the input. Then use `$.watch` for changes to the model. This helps keep all the code inside the controller within angular context. Is rare in any angular application not to use `ng-model` on any form controls

```html
 <input type="text"  class="datepicker" datepicker="" ng-model="myDate">
```

Within directive:

```js
dateInput.bind('changeDate',function(){
      scope.$apply(function(){
         scope[attrs.ngModel] = element.val()
      });
});
```

Then in Controller:

```js
$scope.$watch('myDate',function(oldVal,newVal){ 
       if(oldVal !=newVal){
           /* since this code is in angular context will work for the hide/show now*/
            $scope.dateChanged=true;
             $timeout(function(){
                   $scope.dateChanged=false;
              },5000);
        }        
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qxjck/10/

**EDIT** One more item that should change is remove `var dateInput = angular.element('.datepicker')` if you want to use this directive on more than one element in page. It is redundant being used in directive where `element` is one of the arguments in the `link` callback already, and is instance specific. Replace `dateInput` with `element`

Comment: one more thought...there are several angular/bootstrap ui directive projects that are super easy to use on github

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight. I got it working immediately with $apply (I could hug you for that), but I want to do it right so I'm trying to implement the approach you showed. Something I didn't show but should have in my demo is I'm actually using an *<a>* tag to trigger the date picker. The chosen date is held in `element.data('datepicker').getDate()`. I'm new to AngularJS, so please excuse me if I'm wrong, but ng-model is for form elements. What would be a suitable replacement?

Comment: not as familiar with bootstrap datepicker as i am with jQuery Ui one. However instead of using `ng-model` on an input, can hard code the variable to update in controller scope, or use any custom attribute you want to store the variable name( if using this in multiple places in page for example). Have more problems,  create updated version with `<a>` tag implementation. Source of value as data on elemnt easy to modify in the `scope.$apply` call in directive. Keep same `$watch` methodlogy.

Comment: cool... is a bit frustrating at first figuring out nuances of angular, but well worth it in long run

Comment: Instead of `scope[attrs.ngModel]`, the [$parse](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$parse) service should be used because $parse will work even if your ng-model value is `obj.myDate` -- [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/UUNTD/).  `scope[attrs.ngModel]` won't work in that case.

Answer (score 2):

The changeDate event bound to the input seems to be set up to fire outside of the Angular framework. To show the paragraph, call [`$scope.$apply()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply) after setting `dateChanged` to true. To hide the paragraph after the delay, you can use `$apply()` again inside the function passed to `setTimeout`, but you're likely to keep out of further trouble using Angular's [`$timeout()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout) instead.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thisgeek/qxjck/6/)