# Angularjs synchronize the value in different part but under same module same controller

Tags: angularjs, scope

How to synchronize $scope.department in 2 controllers. no matter I enter the value in which input, the $scope.department still can update base on the input field. [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/TLpFQYIhpLT5CV8fQ5h9?p=preview)

```
Angularjs  
var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('GreetCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.department= "HR department";

  });

HTML
<body ng-app="app">
  <div class="show-scope-demo">
    <div ng-controller="GreetCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="department">
      {{department}}
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="GreetCtrl">
     <input type="text" ng-model="department">
     {{department}}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you want `$scope.department` to be `constant`?

Comment: @Henry just Take a look at my Answer

Comment: @Madhu: no, I want it be dynamic

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan: I think you miss understood my question, but anyway thank for giving me a respond. Actually what I want is the $scope.department can be update in both controller at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a constant in `Angular JS` like this.

So `Department` will always contains **"HR department".**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.constant("Department", "HR department");
app.controller('GreetCtrl', function ($scope, Department) {
    $scope.department = Department;

});
```

But you should do something like the below to acheive the scenerio which you have metioned

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uRPSL/56/)**

**html**

```
<div class="show-scope-demo">
    <div ng-controller="GreetCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="department" ng-change="preventChange()">{{department}}</div>
    <div ng-controller="GreetCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="department" ng-change="preventChange()">{{department}}</div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.constant("Department", "HR department");
app.controller('GreetCtrl', function ($scope, Department) {
    $scope.department = Department;
    $scope.preventChange = function () {
        $scope.department = Department;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share the variable between the `controllers` then use `$rootScope`.

assign `$rootScope.department = "somehting"`.

Please refer the below question..

[Sharing scope between controller & directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605931/sharing-scope-between-controller-directive-in-angularjs)

Comment: I had tried, but it cannot work. [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/TLpFQYIhpLT5CV8fQ5h9?p=preview)